# PostGIS: Querying raster data along a path

Tags: postgis, raster, grib, grib-2

I've got a raster loaded into PostGIS that contains grib forecast data which I loaded using `raster2pgsql` using SRID 4326. To keep things simple I am not tiling the raster so I only have one row in my table. After the import, the resulting table contains two columns: `rid` (integer) and `rast` (raster).

The source grib contain data for two points of time, and covers 9 different altitudes. I'm storing two data points for each time and altitude so I've got a total of 36 bands.

How can I query this raster to get a rowset with useful column names containing all available numeric values available for a path over the ground (geometry linestring) over time?

Here's CREATE TABLE for the table that results from running `raster2pgsql`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cat
(
    rid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('cat_rid_seq'::regclass),
    rast raster,
    CONSTRAINT cat_pkey PRIMARY KEY (rid)
);
```

And I can see I have 36 bands when I run this SQL:

```
SELECT ST_NumBands(rast) As num_bands
FROM public.cat;
```

Comment: GIS SE has a policy of "One question per Question". Please **edit** the question to focus on your most pressing issue; you can always ask other questions later. Also, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SQL questions should have SQL code in them.  If you at least start, we'll know the table names and spatial column names.

Comment: Spatial column name provided in the first paragraph. Here's CREATE TABLE statement if that helps.

CREATE TABLE public.cat
(
    rid integer,
    rast raster
)

I don't know where to begin with how to query a raster, hoping someone here on GIS can assist.

Comment: I can see there are 36 bands when I run the following SQL: SELECT ST_NumBands(rast) As num_bands
FROM public.cat;

Comment: Please **edit the question** to improve it.  As per the Tour, comments are used to request clarifications, and clarifications should be made as edits. It's not fair to those who would help you to need to sift though comments to find critical information. SQL code is a *requirement* for SQL questions to be on-topic here.

Comment: Thanks Vince, sorry I don't know what "theme-on-theme overlay of points from lines with a raster" means ... are you saying you want to see SQL for a linestring geometry that I'd like to see output for? I can provide that if you think it's helpful. In the end I'd like to get the actual values relevant to that linestring path in numeric format in a rowset. I'm not too picky on how the rowset is structured as long as it has all the data relevant to the path I'm interested in.